# How to expand multiple cells at once?

Tags: front-end

Is there a simple way to expand multiple cells simultaneously?

At the moment I am primarily interested in fully expanding "in one fell swoop" all the cells in a documentation window, although I can imagine situations in which I'd want to open several cells only one-level deep, so I'm interested in this case as well.  Finally, it would also be useful to know how to collapse multiple cells at once.

EDIT: My immediate interest is for ways to do this interactively, rather than programmatically.  I.e. keyboard (+ mouse) shortcuts, or (second best), menu commands.

---

EDIT (15-06-25): I ultimately dealt with the closed cells in the documentation pages by modifying the relevant stylesheet so that these cells are opened automatically whenever I visit one of those pages.  The solution is a combination of [bill s's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32711/2464) with this [other one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46894/2464), more specifically, the recipe labeled **Update 2015, stylesheet approach**.

The whole solution boils down simply to inserting the following snippet in the appropriate stylesheet file:

```
CellDynamicExpression:>Refresh[FrontEndExecute[{
     FrontEndToken[
      EvaluationNotebook[], "SelectAll"]}]; FrontEndExecute[{
     FrontEndToken[
      EvaluationNotebook[], "SelectionOpenAllGroups"]}], None],
```

...but, since it took me quite a while to figure out how to carry out the recipe given in the [cited answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32711/2464), I thought that I would spell out the missing details here.

1. create (or locate) the file `Reference.nb`, [as described](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32711/2464), and visit it.
2. use `Edit > Find...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to locate a cell with contents

> <sub>Local definitions for style "NotesSection":</sub>
>   **NotesSection**

3. click on this cell's bracket to select it;
4. press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (alternatively, select `Cell > Show Expression`); this reveals an *Mathematica* expression beginning with `Cell[...`;
5. paste the snippet given above at the appropriate location in the `Cell[...` expression, as shown in the [cited answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32711/2464)'s figure;
6. I repeat steps (3) and (4) above (so that the `Cell[...` is no longer visible);
7. I save the notebook (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

Do not skip step 6; the changes did not take effect until I got out of the `Show Expression` state, even after saving the notebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a range of commands that allow you to programmatically control the front end. For example

```
FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectAll"]}];
FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectionOpenAllGroups"]}];
```

selects all the cells and opens them.

```
NotebookFind[InputNotebook[], "Output", All, CellStyle];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"]];
```

May also be of use. The places to look for help about these kind of commands is [`FrontEndToken`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrontEndToken.html) and the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FrontEndTokens.html) or [this help page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FrontEndTokens.html).

Comment: Bill, you missed a couple o'spaces :)

Comment: Thanks! I was actually looking for interactive commands (though I did not make that very clear in my original post). Your answer, however, gave me enough to search with. I found what I was looking for (namely, `Ctrl + {`) under `Cell > Grouping`.